# Round number to next highest greatest place

Tags: c#, math, rounding

Im trying to create a function that will return the next highest (for lack of a better term) "round" number, based on the greatest place digit (left most digit).

For example:

```
 17     >  20  
 328    >  400  
 18564  >  20000

 //Already round numbers will stay the same:  
 500     >  500
```

I know I can just do something like this:

```
int customRound(int i)
{
    string s = i.ToString();
    if (int.Parse(s.Substring(1)) > 0)
    {
        string greatestDigit = s.Substring(0, 1);
        string digit = (int.Parse(greatestDigit) + 1).ToString();
        return int.Parse(digit + string.Empty.PadRight(s.Length - 1, '0'));
    }
    return i;
}
```

But that just feels really hacky and Im sure theres a more elegant and mathematical way to do it.

Comment: Does 1 "round" to 10, 91 "round" to 100, etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Math.Log10 to determine the order-of-magnitude of the number (previous number that is a power of 10), then round up to the next multiple of it:

```
int customRound(int i)
{
    var digits = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(i));
    var unit = (int)Math.Pow(10, digits);
    return (int)(Math.Ceiling((double)i / unit) * unit);
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: This solution does leave values 1-9 unchanged - is that correct?

Comment: @PaulF as it does 10, 20, ... That's how I understood the requirement.

Comment: All other numbers round up to the next value ending with 0. If the requirement is to retain the same number of digits, then 91 should not round to 100.

Comment: @PaulF but what else should 91 round to given the requirement "next highest"?

Comment: Back to my original comment - I would also expect 9 to round up to 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
int customRound(int i)
        {
            return (int)(Math.Ceiling(i / Math.Pow(10, i.ToString().Length-1)) * Math.Pow(10, i.ToString().Length - 1));
        }
```